# Automatic inclusion of the following character, but with its subscripts and superscripts?

Tags: bold, characters, scoping, boldmath

There are such commands as `\vec` which adds an arrow to the top of *the immediate next non-space character*. However, superscripts and subscripts are excluded from the scope.

Now suppose I define a command `\vt` as follows:

```
\newcommand*\vt[1]%
{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

So it acts like `\mathbf`: in math mode, `\vt{}` makes the character inside boldfaced. However, without the brackets, it can also make the next character boldfaced, much like how `\vec` works. Now, suppose I need to make exactly one character boldfaced, but *its subscripts and superscripts also*, without using the brackets (so for example, if I want to mass copy-and-paste the command; the brackets would be a hassle). How can this be done?

Comment: The standard latex syntax always has braces around the mandatory argument. The fact that it can sometimes be omitted for some commands is an unfortunate accident of the implementation. (that said you can use the xparse  package`e` argument type to define this kind of syntax.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting, I was not aware that this is an "unfortunate accident of the implementation" (I was assuming it is a feature for lazy coders).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely not a good idea but certainly possible.  Use `xparse` embellishments.  This will not be as productive in the long run as you think it will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \vt { m e{^_}}
{
  \mathbf{#1}
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\sp{\mathbf{#2}}}
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{\sb{\mathbf{#3}}}
}

\begin{document}

$\vt d$

$\vt d^2$

$\vt d_{x^2 - y^2}$

$\vt d_{x^2 - y^2}^2$

$\vt d^2_{x^2 - y^2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code does not compile for me.  I presume I have something out of date?  `expl3 2016/03/28 v6468`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You need the latest version (`2017/05/29` I believe).  It's the default one in TL2017.

Comment: Well, I just upgraded to `expl3 2017/05/29`  and it still gives me the error `! Missing $ inserted.`  Perhaps I will ask over at chat...

Comment: Joseph and Ulrike helped me out.  I needed not only `l3kernel` updated, but also `l3packages`.  Nice answer!

Comment: This works! Thanks so much -- I got TeXShop to work after updating it to the MacTex 2017 version. One thing though -- the package `siunitx` seems to disable this. Is there a possible way to resolve that? Not that I would ever need the package `siunitx` in the environment I am currently working in, but it would be so nice to know what is happening. (And maybe to resolve a future conflict?)

Comment: Sorry I was confused -- `siunitx` does not disable that, `gb4e` does.